# Extend vendor library in the same namespace

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, composer-php

For example I have installed `ExampleLibrary` using composer. It has some drivers and they are placed under `ExampleLibrary\Driver` namespace.

`ExampleLibrary\Driver\First`, `ExampleLibrary\Driver\Second`, they are extending `ExampleLibrary\DriverInterface`

I want to create my own driver `Third`. Is it ok, if I will place my driver under the vendor namespace?

I will create directory `src/ExampleLibrary/Driver/Third.php` with namespace `ExampleLibrary\Driver`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not use vendors namespaces for your own classes. It is counterintuitive (it is harder to decide who is the author of this class - namespace no longer points vendor) and error-prone (`ExampleLibrary` may add `ExampleLibrary\Driver\Third` class at some point). It may also slow down autoloading (if you're using non-optimized autoloader).